# jquery accessing element via .html() returns undefined

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I am new to jquery, I tried to access the input element via id , I see it returns "undefined" I wrapped it inside document.ready; result is the same, here is the code snippet

```js
let input;

function maintest() {
   input = $("<input>").attr({"id":"test"});
   input.append("#mainDiv");
   $(document).ready( function(){
     alert($("#test").html());
   });

}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<body onload="maintest()">
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

I am surprised it shows "undefined" instead of showing the whole input element when I alert

Comment: What is the value of `input` when you use `$(input).attr({"id":"test"})`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have several problems:

1. You never assigned anything to `input` before calling `$(input)`. If you're trying to create an input element, you need to put a literal string `<input>` in the arguments.
2. You should use `appendTo()`, not `append()`.
3. `input` elements aren't containers, they don't have any HTML in them, so `.html()` won't return anything (it's equivalent to `.innerHTML`, not `.outerHTML`). I changed the script to use `$("#mainDiv").html()`, then it show the `<input>` contained within it.

```js
function maintest() {
  let input = $("<input>").attr({
    "id": "test"
  });
  input.appendTo("#mainDiv");
  $(document).ready(function() {
    alert($("#mainDiv").html());
  });
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.9.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<body onload="maintest()">
  <div id="mainDiv"></div>
</body>
```

Comment: Thanks Barmar but why wouldn't  alert($("#test").html()); output anything?

Comment: What do you expect it to output?

Comment: `.html()` is equivalent to `.innerHTML`, it returns the contents of the element, not the element itself.